# aps_developer_identity.cer to p12 without having to export from Key Chain?

Tags: openssl, apple-push-notifications, pkcs#12

I have a *shed load* of 'aps_developer_identity.cer' certificates exported from iPhone Developer portal. They were all created using the same Certificate Signing Request and (thus) the same private key. If I export just the private key from the Apple Key Chain is it then possible to take the private key and the 'aps_developer_identity.cer' and use openssl to create merged p12/pkcs#12 certificate that I can use on my (Windows) server.

Just to be clear, I know how to get a merged p12 from the Key Chain by exporting both the private key and certificate together, but I want to remove all the extra mouse clicking and typing if I can.

Comment: "They were all created using the same Certificate Signing Request" - Why? In that case they would all be named the same common-name, what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It just needs wrapping up in a shell script.
I am assuming you have downloaded and renamed your 'apple_developer_identity.cer' certificate, here I use 'test.cer', and that you have also exported your developer key from your keychain, in the example below named 'private_dev_key.p12'.

```
#convert *.cer (der format) to pem
openssl x509 -in test.cer -inform DER -out test.pem -outform PEM

#convert p12 private key to pem (requires the input of a minimum 4 char password)
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out private_dev_key.pem -in private_dev_key.p12

# if you want remove password from the private key
openssl rsa -out private_key_noenc.pem -in private_key.pem

#take the certificate and the key (with or without password) and create a PKCS#12 format file
openssl pkcs12 -export -in test.pem -inkey private_key_noenc.pem -certfile _CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest  -name "test" -out test.p12
```

NOTE: If you think this all a bit long winded to achieve what can be done with a few mouse clicks and the typing of the name of a file, then consider the case where you have 20 Apps that you want to enable for notifications. Each App has a development and production certificate, which expire in 4 and 12 months respectively. That is a very boring and error prone job...

Comment: where does the "_CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest" come from? I remember having this file once in the very beginning when creating a dev cert O_o

Comment: There are detailed instructions of how to create the CSR here: http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/11/generate-apple-push-notification.html
I added the underscore to mine because I keep in the same folder as all my other certs and that way it is the first in the list...

Comment: The _CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest issue is absolutely unclear and needs to be explained. The link doesn't elaborate on this. I know how to produce one with keychain but am constantly getting the error "No certificate matches private key" when I use it in the above script... why? exactly what certSigningRequest is being referred to in the above?

Answer (score 4):

I have dropped in my shell script below that may help others. I have several of the keys to deal with and wanted a script as well. This script will output static names for the output files (though that would be simple to change).

example usage (assuming script name):

`$ . thisScript request_file.cer priv_key.p12 aps_dev.cer`

The script:

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
echo "Error in $0 - Invalid Argument Count"
echo "Syntax: $0 request_cer_file p12_file app_cer_file output_filename"
echo "  - request_cer_file      is the request file you sent to apple"
echo "  - p12_file          is found in your keychain (it's the private key)"
echo "  - app_cer_file          is found on App ID screen from Apple"
else

reqFile=$1
p12File=$2
cerFile=$3

certPEM='apn_cert.pem'
pKeyPEM='apn_pkey.pem'
pKeyNoEncPEM='apn_pkey_noenc.pem'
p12FileOut='apn_cert_key.p12'

# remove old
rm $certPEM
rm $pKeyPEM
rm $pKeyNoEncPEM
rm $p12FileOut

#convert *.cer (der format) to pem
openssl x509 -in $cerFile -inform DER -out $certPEM -outform PEM

#convert p12 private key to pem (requires the input of a minimum 4 char password)
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out $pKeyPEM -in $p12File

# if you want remove password from the private key
openssl rsa -out $pKeyNoEncPEM -in $pKeyPEM

#take the certificate and the key (with or without password) and create a PKCS#12 format file
openssl pkcs12 -export -in $certPEM -inkey $pKeyNoEncPEM -certfile $reqFile  -name "apn_identity" -out $p12FileOut

#
#   
#   If all things worked then the following should work as a test
#   openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apn_cert.pem -key apn_pkey_noenc.pem 
#
#
echo "Looks like everything was successful"
echo "Test command:"
echo "openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apn_cert.pem -key apn_pkey_noenc.pem"
echo
fi
```