# How to create P12 certificate for iOS distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate, p12

We have an iOS app whose push notification cert has expired and we're trying to create a new one.  I've created new certs in the Provisioning portal (ios_developer.cer, ios_distribution.cer) and downloaded them.  I was following instructions [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453286/aps-developer-identity-cer-to-p12-without-having-to-export-from-key-chain) to convert it to PEM and then to P12 files, but I'm stuck.  When I then attempt to convert the PEM to P12, it wants a private key of some sort, and I don't know where to get it.

I've also tried loading these into Keychain Access.  I had read that you could export them as P12 from there, but when I do the Import, they don't appear anywhere.

Comment: I found a solution here,https://www.iosenterpriseaccount.com/how-to-create-p12-certificate-for-ios-distribution

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Your private key is generated when you created the signing request in Keychain Access. After the cert is generated and downloaded, double-clicking it will add it to Keychain Access where it will be matched up with the private key. You can then select the cert, and open the arrow to also select the private key and export them together as a .p12 file from Keychain Access.

Comment: Thanks.. okay so it looks like what I need to do is get my employer's certificate imported into my Mac.  But he doesn't have a Mac and we don't know of anywhere it is installed.  Do you know how I can download/import this from the Dev Center?  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind; figured it out.  Man no wonder people have such trouble with this... it's confusing!

Comment: Would be nice but p12 is greyed out for me :(

Comment: @Rob you need to select the private key and not the whole cert. In the Keychains on top left select "Login" then underneath in Category select "certificates" you'll see you cert has a drop arrow now, click it and the private key will show right click and export hat as a .p12

Comment: @rocky What if I don't get the expand option? Does that mean that the key is missing from the cert?

Comment: @user1354603 there should be a public and private key in the same location, public doesn't have the drop select option. Once you created the private key, did you double click it to add it to the keychain? Maybe detail what you've done so far...

Comment: I am not getting the drop-down option either. I double-clicked the certificate after downloading, and it shows up in the login keychain, but not under the private key. I only see it under Certificates, there is no connection between the key and certificate that I can see.

Comment: same here. No dropdown, p12 grayed-out

Comment: @Rob. i accidentally deleted my private key form ke-chain. so now i cant see private key below certificate. i have CSR file how to install private key again from CSR?

Comment: @AvijitNagare You cannot. The CSR does not contain the private key. It was only stored in your keychain unless you manually copied it somewhere else. You will need to generate a new key pair.

Comment: You should not click the dropdown and select both items. Just select the certificate itself and then export. Right click should show "Export certficiate..." not "Export 2 items"

Comment: If you don't see the dropdown arrow on the left of the cert, then first select "Certificates" or "My Certificates", it doesn't display the arrow if you select "All Items" /:

Comment: My private key and my cert seem to be in two different places in keychain.  One under login and the other under login2.  When I export the private key as a .p12 it works but when I upload it to firebase it says "There was an error reading your certificate".

Comment: I had to drag the keys to login2 and then I got the drop down arrow and the export worked properly.  Before that I could export the keys but they would not work.

Answer (score 127):

*.p12 files are used to publish app on the Apple App Store*

**A. On your Mac Create a (.certSigningRequest) CSR file**

1. Open *Keychain Access* from Utilities
2. From Keychain Access toolbar select *Keychain Access -> Preference*
3. In the pop up window select *Certificates* tab
4. Set both *“Online Certificate Status Protocol” and “Certificate Revocation List” to “Off"*
5. Close this window
6. Now from toolbar, open *Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority*
7. Enter email address and common name that you used to register in the iOS Developer Program
8. Keep CA Email blank and select “Saved to disk” and “Let me specify key pair information”
9. Click Continue
10. Choose a filename & destination on your hard drive
11. Click Save
12. In the next window, set “*Key Size” value to “2048 bits”*
13. Set *“Algorithm” to “RSA”*
14. Click Continue

This will create and save your certSigningRequest file (CSR) to your hard drive. A public and private key will also be created in Keychain Access with the Common Name entered.

**B. Create ".cer" file in iOS developer account**

1. Login to apple developer account Click *“Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles”*
2. Click *“Provisioning Profiles”*
3. In the “Certificates” section click *“Production”*
4. Click the *“Add” (+) button at the top-right of the main panel*
5. Now, choose *“App Store and Ad Hoc”*
6. Click Continue
7. Click *“Choose File”* & find CSR file you’ve made from your hard drive
8. Click *Generate*
9. Click *Download* to get the file

**C. Install .cer and generate .p12 certificate**

1. Find *.cer file you’ve downloaded and double-click*
2. Set Login drop-down to *“login" and Click Add*
3. Open up KeyChain Access and you'll find profile created in Step A
4. You can expand *“private key”* profile (shows certificate you added)
5. Select only these two items (not the public key)
6. Right click and click *“Export 2 items…”* from popup
7. Now make sure file format is *“.p12”* and choose filename and destination on your hard drive
8. Click Save. Now, you’ll be prompted to set a password but *keep these both blank*
9. Click OK. Now, you have a .p12 file on your hard drive

Take a note that if issue still persists then try below step as well:

**If your keychain is present in iCloud then remove all keychain content from iCloud and do new setup  in iCloud This should work.**

Comment: i accidentally deleted my private key form ke-chain. so now i cant see private key below certificate. i have CSR file how to install private key again from CSR?

Comment: Had a really hard time figuring out the apple process of getting a .p12 file generated as i am a windows phone guy and this post really helped me understand it.

Comment: Very useful instructions. Thanks a lot. It saved a lot of time.

Comment: Why set 'Online Certificate Status Protocol' and the other to off?

Comment: In my case, just exporting the certificate (parent of private key) worked. Exporting both certificate and private key did not work. Read @Jessicardo's answer below.

Comment: I can't see anything under 'My certificates'. Followed the steps above

Comment: @NazarMedeiros: Do it again. You should be able to see it.

Comment: I have tried it almost 50 times now. Created SigningCertificateRequest on my new mac. Uploaded it to the developer portal to be able to download Apple Push notifications certificate. When double clicking on it, certificate is not imported to „my certificate“

Comment: I solved this issue. To explain you what I did: Make sure that your keychain doesn't appear in the iCloud. Once it is there, there is a risk that you get the issue above. I deinstalled everything, made a new setup without using the data in my iCloud, then it worked.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but what do you mean Keep them both blank ( Step C.8 above)? Keep the passwords blank? I tried that, but when trying to publish via Animate 2020 it requires a password for the p.12 file?

Answer (score 43):

you will not get the expand option unless you filter by choosing (Certificates) from key chain left bottom corner

Answer (score 41):

OK, problem solved! it seems that when i double click on the certificate, it automatically installs it in the SYSTEM keychain - i don't know why. So instead, i simply drag and drop the certificate into the LOGIN keychain and then all is good. Thanks to this article -> [Adding certificates to keychain and generating .p12 file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315205/adding-certificates-to-keychain-and-generating-p12-file-format) - alon rosenfeld 10 months ago

Comment: Oh, wow. I spent hours trying to figure this out. I would have wasted another week if it weren't for this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasted hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Yep, wasted hours of time, saved :)

Comment: Still works in 2020. This answer saved a macbook that was about to be smashed into the wall after two days of fighting "No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile."

Answer (score 12):

To get your p12 file go this way..

**Step 1.** In **XCode** > Go to **Project settings** > **General** > **Signing** section > **Signing Certificate**

See which certificate you are using for this particular app as shown in image below

[image]

**Step 2.** Open **Keychain** > on Left bottom **Category** section > **Certificates**

Look for the certificate and open child by clicking on down arrow as show in image

[image]

**Step 3.** Right click and **export** as "Certificates.p12" by giving your password eg. "123456"

Comment: I don't have that arrow to expand

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else having the greyed/grayed out P12 option:

> Make sure you are in the My Certificates or Certificates category in
>   Keychain Access.

https://sailthru.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000032546-Can-t-export-my-certificate-in-p12-format

Comment: Totally saved me 

Comment: That's where the intenet is for 

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else having the greyed/grayed out P12 option,

here is the latest screenshot (2021) from my macbook pro.

[image: keychain access v11.0]

Comment: this step is crucial!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still having this issue, the solution for me was to NOT select both and "Export 2 items" (the key and the certificate) - rather just export the certificate which ALREADY includes the key. As of 2016 i think this is the way to do it because previous uploads that worked with the export 2 items no longer work.

Comment: I can't export only the certificate as p12 - are you sure this is the correct way?

Comment: Same here. This is very important.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up here as I was trying to build an iOS app in the cloud using [MS Visual Studio App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter) WITHOUT a Mac.  The issue is every tutorial uses the top rated answer above by Jayprakash Dubey.  That approach uses a Mac and KeyChain.  The solution comes from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40017778/372055).

You need a Key (aps_development.key), and then:

1. Create key pair : openssl genrsa -out aps_development.key 2048
2. Create CSR : `openssl req -new -sha256 -key aps_development.key -out aps_development.csr`
3. Upload the CSR to developer portal to get the certificate
   `aps_development.cer`
4. Convert the certificate: `openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in aps_development.cer -out aps_development.pem`
5. Build the PKCS#12: `openssl pkcs12 -inkey aps_development.key -in aps_development.pem -export -out aps_development.p12`

You can then go ahead and make an app id and a provisioning profile.  This will allow you to build in the App Center.

Comment: App Center itself does use Macs in the Cloud to build iOS apps. App Center Build also expects your app is able to build in a local Mac environment. 

So this approach is unsupported and could have unforeseen issues, even if it works right now.

Comment: @MattPil29 Where did you download .key file from?

Comment: I needed to use my Windows machine to generate the CSR and convert the CER to P12 for CodeMagic and these instructions worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

In order to **create P12 certificate for iOS distribution**, First of all you will need to create a certificate from your Apple developer account.

[image: cert1]

Click on `+` button and choose `IOS Distribution (App Store and Ad Hoc)`, click `Continue`.

[image: cert2]

you will be asked to upload a Signing Request Certificate, that has to be created on your Mac

[image: cert3]

open `Keychain Access` **=>** `Certificate Assistant` **=>** `Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority`.

Btw you will need to create the certificate within your `login` keychain (as shown in the image), if it doesn't exist within your keychain, search how to add it.

[image]

type your `User Email Address`, and a `Common Name`, leave `CA Email Address` *empty*, and check on `Saved to disk`, **=>** `Continue` and specify where you want to save it.

[image]

upload the certificate that you generated to where we were on your developer apple account, and `Continue` **=>** `Download` choose where you want to download it

[image]

Double click on the `ios_distribution.cer` that you downloaded from developer apple account, and open `Keychain Access`, you will find that your certificate has been add to your login keychain.

[image]

click on `My Certificates` tab and **Select** both your certificate with its private key, then Export both of them at the same time, and choose `.p12` as an extension.

[image]

[image]

Now you could work with your newly generated **P12 certificate for iOS distribution**