# Adding certificates to keychain and generating .p12 file format

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I am following the step given in https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp to while working step by step for Apple Push Notifications.

I got stuck in the middle. I added Apple Push Notification development Certificates. But the certificates appears under SYSTEM/Certificates instead of LOGIN/Certificates section. May be due to this or may be not, I did't get save as .p12 file format option when i try to save file as p12 format as explained in step 19. I also tried generating certificates without  checking 
LET MY SPECIFY KEY PAIR CHAIN INFORMATION as explained in step 10.

Can anybody suggest me how to make aps-development.cer under login/certificates in key chain and then proceed the given step to obtain .p12 file?

Thanks in advance for your help and support.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please try following Three steps

Step 1:Open your Keychain Access app.

Step 2:You will see list in left side as 'Login' ,'System' and 'System Roots', just drag your certificate in 'Login' option.

Step 3: You will get certificate install successfully in Keychain Access.

After this process you can create the .p12 certificate.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this did not work for me. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @DNagy what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Step by step instruction how to download certificate and generate .p12**

You need a valid certificate to be able to generate .p12 file. Step 1-3 describe steps to download valid certificate from the Apple Developer Account. Step 4-8 describe how to use this certificate to generate .p12 file.

1. Logon to DEVELOPER.APPLE.COM
2. (From the left menu) Go to 'Certificates, ID's & Profiles' or (From the main panel) Click on 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles'
3. (From the left menu) Click on Certificate type ie Production -> Click on the Certificate name to expand more options -> Click on 'Donwload'
4. (From the mac menu) Go to Utilities -> Key Chain
5. (From the top menu of Key Chain) Go to Key Chain Access
6. Open location where certificate has been downloaded and double click on it (This should auto generate new record in the Key Chan Access certificate list)
7. (From the Key Chain Access certificate list) right click on the newly created certificate record and choose 'Export...'
8. Save file as .p12

Comment: There is no option for me to export as p12 file. The certificate doesn't even appear in 'My certificates'. I followed the steps above..

Answer (score 1):

To generate a self-signed SSL certificate using the OpenSSL, complete the following steps:

Write down the Common Name (CN) for your SSL Certificate. The CN is the fully qualified name for the system that uses the certificate. For static DNS, use the hostname or IP address set in your Gateway Cluster (for example. 192.16.183.131 or dp1.acme.com).
Run the following OpenSSL command to generate your private key and public certificate. Answer the questions and enter the Common Name when prompted.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem
```

Review the created certificate:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.pem
```

Combine your key and certificate in a PKCS#12 (P12) bundle:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -export -out certificate.p12
```

Validate your P2 file.

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -noout -info
```

Once the certificate file is created, it can be uploaded to a keystore.