# Xcode profile missing public keys

Tags: xcode, certificate

I got myself a new mac so I went into Xcode 4.6.2 and exported my developer account and then on my new iMac I imported the profile and all certificates were imported correctly into keychain app and all private keys were also imported but none of the public keys came across to new account I have now tried to repeat this twice more and Still no luck so I have backed up the old keychain as I can move all key and certificates in one go but I have heap of crap in old keychain that I dont want to bring across has any one else been able to move there profile from one mac to another and get it to copy all keys (public + private) or are the public key not needed for anything I know how keys work for ssh or ssl but I'm not sure whats needed for code signing projects.

Comment: Did you export the .p12 files from the keychain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418661/how-to-create-p12-certificate-for-ios-distribution

Comment: -1 for unreadable statements WITHOUT PUNCTUATIONS

Answer (score 0):

For code signing projects You need a distribution profile and developer profile. You can **download or Import** your profiles from xcode itself. goto Xcode->window->Organizer import option which is used to import your profiles. Signin Option which is used to download the profiles from online.

Comment: I've exported the developer profile from xcode and imported it to xcode on new mac and I get every thing but the public keys and I have downloaded the profile from the web sites as well . I can run my apps the only thing that worries me is the missing public keys .

Comment: I solved this problem. I also previously used mac os 10.6 with xcode 4.3. After changing my cpu i got same error. For this i revoked my certificate from my developer account and i generated new keychain request and i upload the file. After creating this new certificate Again i import the certificate to xcode Now its working fine. Can u please try this definitely it will work...

Comment: before trying this please remove all certificates from xcode->organizer

Comment: I didnt want to have to recreate my key & cert but it looks like I have to  but I have had no issue building with missing public keys, Thank for your help .