# How do I deal with the distribution on a project I've somewhat taken over?

Tags: ios, xcode, signing, profiles

I've recently taken over a project as a freelancer. I have during the development used my own account so I changed most of the debug/release/etc to my own "iPhone developer" etc in the project.

Now, however, it is time to send the update to the actual app store. I've gotten access to the last developers account, I've downloaded the distribution profiles which I assume I need.

The problem now is that, as far as I understand, I need the last developers ".developerprofile" for signing purposes. Or is there some other way? I can't seem to download it from the apple developer account.

This is the first time I am doing any kind of release so I am a bit shaky on the whole provisioning stuff as I've only developed locally and for that xcode manages everything perfectly so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can you need to get the P12 file from the previous developer - [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418661/how-to-create-p12-certificate-for-ios-distribution)

Comment: After I got the .p12 file I could upload the binary.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need the previous developer's certificate or provisioning profiles in order to continue the project on your own.

It's relatively easy to revoke the previous developer's certificate and provisioning profiles (via the Apple Developer Portal) and recreate new ones on your machine.

Once you log into http://developer.apple.com/ios, look for the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section.

Comment: My understanding was though if its been submitted with one set of credentials, you have to submit any updates with those same credentials?

Comment: It sounds like Jonathan (the O.P.) will be submitting it under the old account that you've acquired.  If that's the case, he should be fine with new certificates & provisioning profiles that can be created with that old account

Comment: But if existing project using apple push notification service, any issue he will face? (may be server side developer needs new .pem file or .p12 file.)

Comment: Great question @Prasad! As far as I can tell (and I may be wrong here), push notification is associated with the application ID and once new certificates / provisioning profiles are generated, a new .pem / .p12 file can be sent up for development and/or deployment (when it's time to ship).