# Can an Apple Certificate be transferred between computers?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am working on an app, built in Unity, and have built it to launch on Android and it works fine.  I work on a PC.

I am now trying to convert the code to iOS.  I have borrowed a friend's MacBook Air in order to meet the requirements needed for Apple.  The first step requires me to make certificates.

I do not own this laptop. Does the certificate stay with the machine or is it just a file I can save into the cloud?

Also is the certificate required for updates in the future?

I ran into an issue previously where I created a certificate in Google Play and accidently deleted it, which forced me to make a whole new app.  This made a whole bunch of other issues occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the p12 files then that way you can use the certificates on another system. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418661/how-to-create-p12-certificate-for-ios-distribution)

Add these p12 files to your system keychain on another mac and you are good to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will try this!

Comment: Sure hope this helps you out. Feel free to get back to me in case of further clarification or errors.