# How does third party IOS Development work without access to enterprise license?

Tags: ios, xcode, enterprise

I am currently caught between two companies, one is my own who have a policy of not giving access to their Apple Enterprise development license. The other is a company that wants to customize their IOS app for us.

The 3rd party company wants us to invite them to our Enterprise agreement, our security department have refused.

My question, can the third party developer design and build an IOS application for us, without being given access to the enterprise license? (assuming our developers will sign the application for them)

Comment: @Mark Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Each Enterprise Account has 3 access levels. The Member access level has only read access to your Enterprise Developer account. Meaning that member has only read only or limited access to your certificates and provisioning profiles. 
So, you can give only Member access to Third Party company so that they can sign the App using your Enterprise Account. If you don't want to provide the access to Enterprise account or member access level, you've to provide them Certificate (.p12 format) & Distribution Provisioning profile to sign & distribute the app (see below reference for creating p12 certificate)

- **Team Agent:**
  Available to developers enrolled as an individual or an organization
  The person who completes enrollment automatically becomes the Team Agent. There can only be one Team Agent.
- **Admin:** 
  Available only to developers enrolled as an organization
  Admins serve as a secondary contact for teams and have many of the same responsibilities as Team Agents.
- **Member:**
  Available only to developers enrolled as an organization
  Members have access to membership benefits but have limited responsibilities.

Reference:
 [Apple Developer Program Team Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)
[How to create .p12 certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28962937/1025063)

Hope it helps!