# React-Native Xcode Provisioning profile is not working on other MacBook

Tags: react-native

I have setup React-native project on MacBook, for that i have created development, distribute key from development account. now my MacBook is no working and i have setup application on other systems but that key is not working on another system

1. I have the re-login account and download certificate manually
2. Automatically signing certificate
   But nothing works for me

I have also attached the screenshot of Xcode signing issue with error

[image: image of xcode]

Comment: Showing me error like - Provisioning profile "XXX" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: XXX".

Comment: I think you need to refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418661/how-to-create-p12-certificate-for-ios-distribution