# App Center - Project bundle identifier does not match specified provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xamarin, appcenter

I'm day two into App Center and trying to Build an Ios App (xamarin forms).  Android worked beautifully and deployed to device without issue.  iOs is tricky.
I've signed up as an apple developer
Created required signing certificates, profiles etc per doco online resulting in a .mobileprovision and p12 file being uploaded into App Center for the build.

Build fails with line
**Project bundle identifier 'com.companyname.test1234' does not match specified provisioning profile 'UUID'** (UUID is some unique key, I dont know where it came from)

I've followed the process in this post
[How to create P12 certificate for iOS distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418661/how-to-create-p12-certificate-for-ios-distribution)
for creating my p12 file.

I've gone through the process multiple times end to end trying multiple things and always ending with the same result.

I've found posts in google with similar problems, however no solution.

I have a pc and a mac (using the mac for 3 days).  The solution builds and runs on the emulator on the mac via visual studio (cloned azure devops repo).

My code is stored in Azure Devops.  Everything links seamlessly in App Center I just cannot overcome this problem.

Can anyone assist or point me in the direction of some good end to end doco?
Please let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks
Keegan

Comment: are you manually creating the profile in the dev portal, or letting VS create it for you?  Is the PP you create using the same App ID that is used as the bundle ID in info.plist?

Comment: Hi Jason.  I'm manually creating the profile via the apple developer portal. Yes the provisioning profile' App ID has the same value as the CFBundleIdentifier string defined in my info.plist.  I have noticed though that the app ID in the apple dev portal has another ID in front of it e.g. xxxxxxx.com.companyname.Relyfy.  From what I've read online this is the bundle id?  Thanks for helping, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Further to the above.  I'm a little unclear of the type of Provisioning Profile I should be setting up for app center i.e. Development or Distribution.